# Slow responses from Make, Model, Year from MySQL database using Xcart

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database, x-cart

We are having a issue with our car selector on our website. Currently from my understanding something like this is happening to return results from database

Currently this is what is happening :

```
select * from xcart_makes;   // returns all makes


select * from xcart_models
    where makeid = 45;   // returns models for makeid 45


select * from xcart_product_makes
    where makeid = 45 and modelid = 4;   // returns years for that make and model
```

as there are about ~2,979,081 items

Some Make, Model Year Combos are locking the system up and causing over a 15 second response time. An example to replicate this issue would be going to 
http://www.ultrarev.com
and selecting from the drop box this combo

Chevrolet > Corvette > 2009

That combo will lock the system up, but most others wont.

For example. This combo will pass with little response time

Audi > A3 > 2007

I hope that clears up the issue and can help us to find a solution.

Comment: How do you know that the database is the bottleneck?

Comment: No matter if you have so many items, what you are missing (and I am almost 100% sure) are the indexes in your tables. Go on and add index to all columns you address in `where` clausule: `makeid` in `xcart_models`, also in `xcart_product_makes` and `modelid` in `xcart_product_makes`. You should get results in second.